# OpenSSL split message into two records

Tags: c++, sockets, ssl, tcp, openssl

I developed a SSLProxy as a man in the middle between client and server. Handshaking between client-proxy and proxy-server doing well. I receive a message from client and decrypt it with client_side SSL. Then encrypt it with server_side SSL. All thing is good except on thing: OpenSSL received all the message data in one SSL record but it sent them in 2 SSL records.

**Question:** How can I force OpenSSL to send data in 1 SSL record, because server configured only to use 1 SSL record?

**Wireshark Screen:**

[image]

1. 192.168.2.127 is client.
2. 192.168.0.230  is server.

**Update**: I need something like [this](https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/ssl/SSL_CTX_set_split_send_fragment.html). I tried to use them but I faced with this error:

```
error: ‘SSL_CTX_set_split_send_fragment’ was not declared in this scope
```

Comment: TCP is a stream oriented protocol and should be agnostic regarding the number of used IP packets. However I know that a lot of services expect data to be send in certain chunks because the developers did not implement the incoming data reading code correctly. Anyway you will not get much help here if you don't provide some code. Edit your question and add the code you use for receiving and sending TCP data.

Comment: OpenSSL will insert "empty" fragments of the SSL message, yielding multiple TCP packets, depending on the ciphersuite used; see [this OpenSSL advisory](https://www.openssl.org/~bodo/tls-cbc.txt) and the [`SSL_OP_DONT_INSERT_EMPTY_FRAGMENTS](https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/ssl/SSL_CTX_set_options.html) option.  These empty fragments _might_ explain the multiple SSL packets/messages you see.

Comment: @Heil_Me - Please forgive my ignorance... What is the problem or the question?

Comment: @Robert: It's not belong to TCP connection, OpenSSL handle this part.

Comment: @jww: The question and problem is "How can I force OpenSSL to send data in 1 SSL record, because server configured only to use 1 SSL record?"

Comment: @Heil_Me - If I am parsing things correctly, you wrote the [proxy|interception] server; you don't control the clients. Anything you might be able to do with an OpenSSL client will not apply to Android, Bouncy Castle, Botan, BoringSSL, iOS, Java, .Net, NSS, \<favorite TLS library\> clients; nor will it apply to other user agents like `wget`, `curl` and browsers. It seems like the course of action is to fix the server.

Comment: @Robert: Both TCP and SSL-then-TLS are defined as stream services that don't preserve boundaries. But in practice nearly all TCP implementations since BSD do frequently fragment data of 1500 or less on anything but loopback, so most TCP developers have encountered the issue and learned to read-more-until-done. Most SSL/TLS implementations did _not_ fragment below 16KB until BEAST mitigation in 2012 forced it, so plently of SSL/TLS developers did _not_ learn.

Comment: Heil_me: I concur with @jww server _should_ handle this, and other stacks will do the same _possibly_ except first, but: anti-BEAST fragmentation is not needed for and AFAICT **not applied to TLS1.1 and 1.2** (which don't have the IV flaw) and they are preferable anyway. It also is **not used for RC4** ciphersuites; back in 2011 RC4 was actually promoted for BEAST mitigation, but in the years since RC4 has been (largely) broken and now isn't allowed at all by secure SSL/TLS systems -- but if a system is limited to 1.0 and can't handle fragmentation it might be insecure enough to allow RC4.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 & jww: Actually the server is MSSQL 2008 R2 and I can't change it!

Comment: You still haven't told us why you care about this issue.  It doesn't change anything.

Comment: (1) SQLServer back to 2008 reportedly now supports TLS 1.2, which as I said is the best solution; see http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/107820/sql-server-compatibility-with-new-tls-standards (2) Last time I tested (which was years ago) SQLServer doesn't do normal SSL/TLS but rather SSL/TLS wrapped in TDS which Wireshark can't decode; are you sure you're going to SQLServer itself and not some intermediate thing?

Comment: @dave_thompson_085: You are right. SQLServer use TDS protocol and encapsulate SSL in TDS packet. Wireshark version 2+ now can detect SSL in TDS. Microsoft Message Analyzer and Microsoft Network Monitor can also show details of each SSL that encapsulated in TDS. I developed a code using BIO_MEMORY of OpenSSL that completely handle SSL Handshake but after handshaking first message spilit in 2 record that SQL Server doesn't respond any thing.

Comment: Ah -- I haven't changed to Wireshark 2 even today, much less before it was released. Then the previous recommendations stand; in my preferred order: try 1.2 or 1.1; try RC4; try SSL_OP_DONT_INSERT_EMPTY_FRAGMENTS

Comment: @dave_thompson_085: I updated SQL Server to SP3 and install KB3144114 to support TLSv1.2. My Problem solved for now but in older version with TLSv1 it's still remain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With SQL Server 2008 R2 SP3 and update KB3144114 to support TLSv1.2 my problem solved. But In SQL Server 2008 R2 (with TLSv1) problem still remain same as before and I couldn't find any solution for it.

Answer (score 0):

You must use OpenSSL 1.1.X series for using "SSL_CTX_set_split_send_fragment function", that function is not available in older versions.